# Vim status line not changing / clearing

Tags: vim, statusline

No matter what I change status line to with `set statusline` my status line will not change. It looks like

```
".vimrc" 39L, 578C                                           1,1           All
```

with the cursor position and the percentage through the file as well as the filesize and filename. It is the only line at the bottom.

How to I hide or change the status line?

How do I clear the status line?

Why is the status line not working?

Comment: This question is meant to get introduce 'ruler' to those trying to work out what that line is (like I was). Posted here as [vim] was a popular tag, however it may be better on something like superuser.

Comment: posted along the lines of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are looking at is a `ruler` - a "statusline" in a way, but not a `statusline`. What can be changed in it you can see in `help rulerformat`.

If you wish to hide the ruler set `set noruler`, and afterwards enable the statusline with `set laststatus=2` if you wish for every window to have their own statusline (the most common). Depending on what you want in your statusline, you might wish to read `help statusline`, and afterwards put it in `set statusline=... (when adding options add them with set statusline+=... one by one - that way you can more easily turn some on or off).`

As the first line, when setting statusline, set `set statusline=` that way statusline is cleared before it is loaded again. You'll figure this out when you source it the first few times.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking at is the [ruler](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27ruler%27). You can get rid of it with

```
:set noruler
```

However, if you want to customise it, you can use

```
:set rulerformat=
```

and follow the same format as the status line.

Answer (score 1):

To hide the status bar use:

```
:set laststatus=0
```

Comment: +1 i dont see why this was down-voted, it answers the first question and it does work (tried it myself). It would be nice if people would at the least, give a reason for down voting, and possibly give that person a chance to explain their answer further. I think you guys might be misinterpreting what the downvote is for. It's for an answer that is not useful for which this is not the case. And remember, the votes for Q's have DIFFERENT meanings than the ones for A's!!! (they say 'not useful' but what they mean is 'useless' which if that were the case setting laststatus to zero would not work!)